# 2023 AIME I Problem 15. I don't understand one part of the solution.

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

Here's the question for your reference:

> Find the largest prime number $p<1000$ for which there exists a
> complex number $z$ satisfying
>
> - the real and imaginary part of $z$ are both integers;
> - $|z|=\sqrt{p},$ and
> - there exists a triangle whose three side lengths are $p,$ the real part of $z^{3},$ and the imaginary part of $z^{3}.$

Link to solution:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2023_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_15

So, if you look at the solution given, this particular line is what confuses me.

> Denote $z = a + i b$. Thus, $a^2 + b^2 = p$.

Why does $a^2 + b^2$ have to equal to a prime number, under those conditions listed in the question?

Wouldn't it be correct to say that

$|z|^2 = (a + i b)^2 = (\sqrt{p})^2$

$z^2 = a^2 + 2iab - b^2 = p$

And therefore $p = a^2 + 2iab - b^2$? Why is it $p = a^2 + b^2$ instead?

I'm sure I'm missing something here so I'd very much like to know where I'm getting it wrong! Thanks so much!

Comment: It's actually , $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, when you take the modulus of a complex number

Comment: The absolute value squared of z is not what you have written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, your error is that $$|z|^2 \ne z^2.$$  To see why, note that for any complex number $z$, its modulus $|z|$ is **always** a nonnegative real number.  Yet the right hand side, $z^2$, is not necessarily real or nonnegative; e.g., $i^2 = -1$, and $(1+i)^2 = 1^2 + 2i + i^2 = 2i$.

The [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) (also sometimes called magnitude) of a complex number can be geometrically conceptualized as its distance from the origin in the complex plane; e.g., if $z = a + ib$ for real numbers $a, b$, then $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Comment: Your explanation about the distance makes sense! It's a very good illustration and it's probably the easiest way to visualise why $|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.